# How do i correct this particuar instance of Converting circular structure to JSON error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, firebase

The goal is to save user information to MongoDB and display a success message in the UI. The app will ultimately be a Twilio template I can use on my apps.
I expected to send the user data and auth token to a "MongoUtils" class component. Then send the auth token to the middleware. Save the info to the database. And get a successful response.
Instead, the auth token passed and the data was saved, but, no success message in the UI. The error message is that of the  " Converting circular structure to JSON error".

The relevant code is as follows:

```js
const { password, displayName } = model;
  const initials = displayName[0] + displayName[1];
  const avColor = `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
  const email = `${window.localStorage.getItem('emailForResgistrant')}`;

  return firebaseService.auth
    .signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('registerSliceYes check 1 --->', result.user);
      dispatch(
        createUserSettingsFirebase({
          ...result.user,
          displayName,
          email,
          initials,
          avColor,
        })
      );
      // send success message
      dispatch(
        showMessage({
          message: `Verification email sent to ${email}. Click the link to complete account`,
        })
      );
```

This is the relevant snippet from the UI client registration slice. I am using redux toolkit. createUserSettingsFirebase ended up being used for sending the data to MongoDB also. Currently sends to both firebase and mongo. This takes us to the userSlice:

```js
export const createUserSettingsFirebase = (authUser) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('userslice check 2 --->', authUser);

  // const guestUser = getState().auth.user;
  //  current user is destructured from the firebase.auth object(not a local variable)
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  console.log('register check 1 --->', currentUser);
  // console.log('register check 1.5 --->', idTokenResult);

  /**
   * Merge with current Settings
   */
  // <--- updates user profile in firebase(only basic info)
  const user = _.merge(
    {},
    {
      uid: authUser.uid,
      from: 'firebase',
      role: ['admin'],
      data: {
        displayName: authUser.displayName,
        email: authUser.email,
        initials: authUser.initials,
        avColor: authUser.avColor,
        redirectUrl: '/apps/chat',
      },
    }
  );
  currentUser.updateProfile(user.data);
  // updates user profile in firebase(only basic info) --->

  // this updates the firebase db by ultimately making a call to firebase
  const idTokenResult = await currentUser.getIdTokenResult();

  dispatch(updateUserData(user));
  dispatch(updateUserDataMongoDB(authUser, idTokenResult.token));

  return dispatch(setUserData(user));
};
```

Some of the notes are for my memory. The key action here is the updateUserDataMongoDB action. It is also located in the userSlice:

```js
export const updateUserDataMongoDB = (authUser, authtoken) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('updateUserDataMongoDB', authtoken);

  await MongoUtils.updateUserDataTwo(authUser, authtoken)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('mongo success message');
      dispatch(showMessage({ message: 'User data saved to MongoDB' }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('mongo error message', error);
      dispatch(showMessage({ message: error.message }));
    });
};
```

And finally, the MongoUtils class component:

```js
static updateUserDataTwo(authUser, authtoken) {
    if (!authUser) {
      return false;
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/complete-user`,
          { authUser },
          {
            headers: {
              authtoken,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // handle error
          console.trace('MongoDB Utility Error(updateUserDataTwo)', error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

Also, the mongoose middleware:

```js
exports.authCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('authcheck ---->', req.headers); //token
    try {
        const firebaseUser = await admin
            .auth()
            .verifyIdToken(req.headers.authtoken);
        
        console.log('FIREBASE USER PASSED AUTHCHECK', firebaseUser)
       req.user = firebaseUser;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(401).json({
            err: "Invalid or expired token",
        });
    }
};
```

I tried different code structures in my mongo class. I managed to save to the db but no Promise resolution. The error is as follows:

```js
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 MongoDB Utility Error(updateUserDataTwo) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'D'
    |     property 'c' -> object with constructor 'D'
    |     property 'b' -> object with constructor 'Dc'
    --- property 'a' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at transformRequest (defaults.js:52)
    at transform (transformData.js:16)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:247)
    at transformData (transformData.js:15)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:30)
overrideMethod  @   react_devtools_backend.js:2540
(anonymous) @   MongoUtils.js:46
Promise.catch (async)       
(anonymous) @   MongoUtils.js:43
updateUserDataTwo   @   MongoUtils.js:30
(anonymous) @   userSlice.js:189
(anonymous) @   index.js:8
dispatch    @   redux.js:659
(anonymous) @   userSlice.js:61
await in (anonymous) (async)        
(anonymous) @   index.js:8
dispatch    @   redux.js:659
(anonymous) @   registerSlice.js:121
```

The app works but obviously something doesn't and I can't display the message in the UI. Thanks for your input!

Edit: This is the user logged to console... not sure if this may shed some light or not:

```js
Im {N: Array(0), l: 'AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0', m: '[DEFAULT]', s: 'twilio-3915f.firebaseapp.com', a: Ii, …}
$: Fn {l: false, settings: em, app: FirebaseAppImpl, a: Ii, P: Array(0), …}
Aa: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgwNTg1Zjk5MjExMmZmODgxMTEzOTlhMzY5NzU2MTc1YWExYjRjZjkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.cWLpobXqqjp5zq_RHRCLr78CPxyVLmlL6t-Eo7_U0R6Kgsgma8bQJp_WYZEXgKfF4wgEK4XhjSfuCy2rdreaJ70NgFdeCSQdibJiPSyY_ORMkBbR8s3ux32sWKMw9HPj1YMyu-oo2INGLbi7ttwmI9fmlNMJy3SXe-VS1j7-Eo1C4FCQ6m1m2S0O59oh2QVOjuEcqwHe9c0GwRn7Edw-0ozpeCvW0pS6Df_N79c24aFhg6XgtqVLzfgfAhRheDEO1sSCl1XvLOyeMYxcSr49YvQ0dv5a8H412q7Wohc3XV4XnPd-M-C1EQNNmHnnwJBx_dT2TEO4rmIn_pJEICp6Zw"
Ba: ƒ (f)
D: xm {c: 30000, f: 960000, h: ƒ, i: ƒ, g: ƒ, …}
N: []
Oa: ƒ (f)
P: true
Pa: ƒ (f)
S: tm {a: Im, b: Array(0), enrolledFactors: Array(0), c: ƒ}
W: [ƒ]
a: Ii {c: 'AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0', l: 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token', m: Ze, g: {…}, h: 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/', …}
aa: []
b: Gl {i: {…}, u: 0, D: 'twilio-3915f.firebaseapp.com', v: 'AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0', m: '[DEFAULT]', …}
ba: ƒ ()
bc: Im {N: Array(0), l: 'AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0', m: '[DEFAULT]', s: 'twilio-3915f.firebaseapp.com', a: Ii, …}
displayName: "lopezjesse1277@gmail.com"
email: "championslandscape1@gmail.com"
emailVerified: true
h: Am {f: Ii, a: 'AFxQ4_ov0xeye6FQ23KAFH4b4Lb-7npe34-sGKQwWZYVeX2r8p…xI5aTc1c2NUTKILj-tbExZ38iwtqLppZUgQXTqHi_zMJ8C25I', b: hg, c: 1638068141823}
ha: tn {a: 'AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0:[DEFAULT]', b: Tk}
hb: null
i: null
isAnonymous: false
ja: Fn {l: false, settings: em, app: FirebaseAppImpl, a: Ii, P: Array(0), …}
l: "AIzaSyCHVffqdXsT1_NypdTU2F29NhOUbSG-lw0"
m: "[DEFAULT]"
metadata: Fm {a: '1638053351217', b: '1638053351217', lastSignInTime: 'Sat, 27 Nov 2021 22:49:11 GMT', creationTime: 'Sat, 27 Nov 2021 22:49:11 GMT'}
multiFactor: tm {a: Im, b: Array(0), enrolledFactors: Array(0), c: ƒ}
pa: undefined
phoneNumber: null
photoURL: null
providerData: [{…}]
qa: Fn {l: false, settings: em, app: FirebaseAppImpl, a: Ii, P: Array(0), …}
refreshToken: "AFxQ4_ov0xeye6FQ23KAFH4b4Lb-7npe34-sGKQwWZYVeX2r8p2OXV_dvhY6G1vQIZ80Y-kKUr2YmQqPDwE2kbVl-_04iweIczJotfXPXjeGGcKrpc86virbSR4Tpp4r0jxBDXjDXjhm8BLKgjMLQ805REE2-4CxfWYlQzEi9VsFziNcEczNRzL-uiiH97vR3mQgwsBMcSwLogufOyfjzhXYumwxI5aTc1c2NUTKILj-tbExZ38iwtqLppZUgQXTqHi_zMJ8C25I"
s: "twilio-3915f.firebaseapp.com"
tenantId: null
u: null
uid: "kJbLUMOf72WOXKGiNuy3a3ZEEHR2"
v: hd {src: Im, a: {…}, b: 4}
ya: false
za: null
_lat: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgwNTg1Zjk5MjExMmZmODgxMTEzOTlhMzY5NzU2MTc1YWExYjRjZjkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.cWLpobXqqjp5zq_RHRCLr78CPxyVLmlL6t-Eo7_U0R6Kgsgma8bQJp_WYZEXgKfF4wgEK4XhjSfuCy2rdreaJ70NgFdeCSQdibJiPSyY_ORMkBbR8s3ux32sWKMw9HPj1YMyu-oo2INGLbi7ttwmI9fmlNMJy3SXe-VS1j7-Eo1C4FCQ6m1m2S0O59oh2QVOjuEcqwHe9c0GwRn7Edw-0ozpeCvW0pS6Df_N79c24aFhg6XgtqVLzfgfAhRheDEO1sSCl1XvLOyeMYxcSr49YvQ0dv5a8H412q7Wohc3XV4XnPd-M-C1EQNNmHnnwJBx_dT2TEO4rmIn_pJEICp6Zw"
[[Prototype]]: H
```

Comment: The solution to that problem is to create your own object that does not contain any circular references.  JSON cannot represent objects with circular references - the spec just doesn't support it.  Can you explain more specifically in your code exactly where the error occurs?  If you don't know, then add a whole bunch more error detection so you can see the error the moment it happens and know exactly where it starts.

Comment: As far as where the error originates... it is showing up in the catch block mongo utils component that sends the auth token to the database. Not sure if it's some kind of firebase error. I understand what you mean except that I'm not sure what the error is referencing. or what code is the problematic code.

Comment: I'm editing the post with the user from firebase logged to the console.

Comment: You're showing us tons of stuff ... everything except the only thing that matters.  Q: What is the JS object that has the circular reference???  Can you show us the incoming data at the point of failure?  In other words: Q: Can you set a breakpoint at react_devtools_backend.js:2540  and display the data you're passing into JSON.stringify?  We need to know more than 'b', 'c', 'D' and "Dc'...

Comment: Can you share the code for your `/complete-user` endpoint? or is the error on client side only ? what actually are you trying to add in Mongo?

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js is your code, isn't it?  Can you set a breakpoint at line 2540 and look at the data it looks like you're trying to stringify()?

Comment: This has been a learning experience in debugging. Which I will be studying. This ended up being that I didn't utilize code that already existed... an object I created using the user from firebase. Edited above...

Answer (score 1):

And answered, as jfriend00 explained(not sure how to mark his comment as an answer):

```js
export const createUserSettingsFirebase = (authUser) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('userslice check 2 --->', authUser);

  // const guestUser = getState().auth.user;
  //  current user is destructured from the firebase.auth object(not a local variable)
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  console.log('register check 1 --->', currentUser);
  // console.log('register check 1.5 --->', idTokenResult);

  /**
   * Merge with current Settings
   */
  // <--- updates user profile in firebase(only basic info)
  const user = _.merge(
    {},
    {
      uid: authUser.uid,
      from: 'firebase',
      role: ['admin'],
      data: {
        displayName: authUser.displayName,
        email: authUser.email,
        initials: authUser.initials,
        avColor: authUser.avColor,
        redirectUrl: '/apps/chat',
      },
    }
  );
  currentUser.updateProfile(user.data);
  // updates user profile in firebase(only basic info) --->

  // this updates the firebase db by ultimately making a call to firebase
  const idTokenResult = await currentUser.getIdTokenResult();

  dispatch(updateUserData(user));
  dispatch(updateUserDataMongoDB(authUser, idTokenResult.token));

  return dispatch(setUserData(user));
};
```

I mistakenly sent the firebase response.user(as authuser) to the database. I instead sent the user as defined in createUserSettingsFirebase. And, magically, haha, successful promise resolution and the message in the UI.

```js
redux-logger.es.js:659  action message/showMessage @ 19:51:52.405
redux-logger.es.js:679  prev state 
{auth: {…}, rise: {…}, i18n: {…}, chatApp: {…}}
redux-logger.es.js:687  action     
{type: 'message/showMessage', payload: {…}}
payload: {message: 'User data saved to MongoDB'}
type: "message/showMessage"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```